# How would you describe/label the ability to do good layout (in the old Desktop Publishing sense)

Tags: page-layout, design-principles, designers

When I am searching for designers, I find that an important skill is "layout"  in the old DTP sense.

The ability to position things on a page in a logical, attractive fashion.

Do the kids these days still call that "layout"?

Comment: maybe 'print layout' to differentiate it from web layout?

Comment: the *ability* to do good layout is "talent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's still referred to as layout.

In some cases "page design" may be used, but that generally is geared more toward web design.

Essentially you layout a print design whereas you design a web page.

Answer (score 0):

`Information Architecture` is a modern description for the skill that people use to organise layouts with a methodical, sometimes scientific approach.

It is used for developing usability and structural aesthetics, the latter of which is more relevant to what you're asking about.

Comment: I'd say this is more geared to web though. IA is rarely used in terms of printing.